# What is the most efficient way to save user preferences in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, structure

I'm wondering what best tactic is for saving a large array of user preferences for a website. Mostly things like default values, like default timezone, default text size, etc. Making a separate column for each setting doesn't sound practical. The only way I can think of currently is to add a singe column in the `users` table for preferences, and put all the settings in there.

For example, I could use formatting like this in one column only: `timezone:GMT;text_size:12;default_value1:something;default_value2:FALSE`. Then when grabbing it in PHP, I would select this column for the logged in user and do an explode on the result, setting $_SESSION['settings']['setting_key'] = "setting_value".

Is there a smarter way to do this, or am I already in the right direction? The only downside to this is not being able to search through each specific setting, of course, since everything is lumped together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMHO that's what [serialize](https://www.php.net/serialize) is just perfectly meant for.

If you want it searchable you might want to end up splitting them up.
On the other hand, you might want to take a totally different approach and instead of storing in a large table with setting per column, you can create a table of a kind:

```
CREATE TABLE settings (user_id INT, setting VARCHAR, value VARCHAR)
```

and store settings like that. Then you are not limited by adding/removing columns.

Another approach (to further speed up possible settings lookups) would be to create a multiple of tables:

```
CREATE TABLE settings (id INT, setting VARCHAR)
CREATE TABLE settings_values (user_id INT, setting_id INT, value VARCHAR)
```

considering that `setting_id` is a foreign key to `settings.id` and assuming that you have some `users` table that has user id's where `user_id` is a foreign key to in both examples.

Comment: How would this deal with different data types? For example, I could have boolean, int, or varchar values. Wouldn't that also pose a problem for being searchable?

Comment: Also, how would your last approach speed things up, to have setting and values in different tables? That would only seem to complicate things.

Comment: You can then look up settings by id, rather than by a string, that select clause will be much faster. Regarding the types, you would have to have a type conversion in the software then I guess. It's not very optimal, but it _is_ a way out of having column per setting :)

Answer (score 2):

I would go for the 'column per preference' option; after all, your program has to store the preferences and then retrieve them, so it's not as if there will be preferences floating around which your program does not know how to handle.

I have a similar system in a database program which I wrote and maintain, in which maybe ten preferences are saved per user per screen. Storing on this basis cuts down on complexity.

How many preferences were you considering to store? I doubt that it would be more than ten.

If you are going to retrieve *all* the preferences in one go then store them *all* at once, then it is possible to use the concatened string approach, but generally I wouldn't recommend this as it makes it more difficult to access the preferences on an individual basis.

Comment: Do you store them in a separate settings column, or right there in the users table? Thanks.

Comment: It depends: as I store data on a per screen basis, the preferences are stored in a separate table with fields user id|screen id|preference 1|preference 2| etc. Atomic data per user can be stored directly in the users table.

Comment: How many columns is too many? I'm around 25 or so.. I could see getting to 50.. would separating not be the best option at this point?

Comment: what about storing them in a "binary" value. Attribute a power of 2 value to each preference. e.g. first preference = 1, second preference = 2, third preference = 4. and then check if the "binary value" has each bit. all the preferences in one int field. Would that be a good thing?